# Arrays in excel change format of string

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I have the data in the image I would like to separate. The code in the image doesn't separate once it gets to the semicolon and indentation. I would like to separate the words onto a new sheet so I'm about to search through the array for certain words.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is always good to provide some test data.

Comment: Instead of splitting each line it stops after the first one and if there were underlines those would disappear as well

Comment: Because you are not looping the rows.

Comment: What should I change to get the rows looping?\

Comment: So you have data in column A and you want to split it and put it in column B, C, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will not only split the data, but also copy over the formatting, which it seems you also wanted.  Assumes data is in Column A

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitWithFormat()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim i As Long, V As Variant

Set R = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
For Each C In R
    With C
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        consecutivedelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=False, _
        Space:=True, other:=False

        .Copy
        Range(.Offset(0, 1), Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
Next C
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is the outcome of the data considered an array?

Comment: @johndoe253  What definition of **array** are you considering?  And why might you think the outcome to not be an array?

Comment: well I would like to be able to search through the outcome for certain words and Im not sure what search function to use

Comment: @johndoe253 Your response doesn't really indicate what you mean by `array` and why you think the results might not be considered an `array`.  With regard to searching for words, there are a number of different ways to do this, making it quite a broad question. I suggest you formulate a new question, and follow the guidelines laid out in HELP for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A question I had about your code: When I run the code if there are and places where theres an indentation it stops and moves to the next cell. A semicolon separates the beginning of the indentation so I changed it to true but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @johndoe253 If your data format is dissimilar to what you presented in your original post, then, yes, the code may not function as you desire.  If you want it to run on data formatted differently, you will need to either alter the data, or alter the code.  If you need help doing so, edit your original post to show the types of format you need to process, and how you want it processed.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verfiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115442/discussion-between-johndoe253-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Comment: @johndoe253  OK, but I don't see you there

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work for an array of size 100, you can modify it to a higher value, or use a dynamic array with `REDIM`.

```
Sub find()

Dim s As String
Dim Data(100) As Variant
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Cells(i, 1).Font.Underline = True
    Cells(i, 2).Value = FindWord(Cells(i, 1), 2) ' change 2 to whatever word position in the original string you want to copy to the right column
Next i

End Sub
```

' And I added this function

```
Function FindWord(Source As String, Position As Integer)

Dim cell_strarr() As String
cell_strarr = Split(Source, " ")
strWordCount = UBound(cell_strarr)
If strWordCount < 1 Or (Position - 1) > strWordCount Or Position < 0 Then
    FindWord = ""
Else
    FindWord = cell_strarr(Position - 1)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: The code works but only splits the first word and move it over one cell. It also removes underlines. How can you fix it?

Comment: @johndoe253, I've added a row for the underline. What do you want to have in the original column ? The whole string ? What do you want to have in the second column ?

Comment: I would like to keep the original string in the left and create the splits next to the original column

Comment: @johndoe253, try the updated code now. You can adjust the parameters you want to retrieve from the original string by modifying the value 2 when calling the `Function FindWord(Source As String, Position As Integer)`

Comment: Thank you for the help! It was much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This following code will assume you have data in column A. It will put values in column B, C, etc...

```
Sub find()

    Dim s As String
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    NumRows = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    s = ActiveCell.Value
    Data = Split(s, " ")

    For i = 0 To NumRows
        Data = Split(Cells(i + 1, 1), " ")
        x = 2
        For j = 0 To UBound(Data)
            Cells(i + 1, x).Value = Data(j)
            x = x + 1
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's much appreciated!