# string array to new sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

The code below executes and splits the original cell into a new array but I cannot get the new string array to move to a new sheet. The line that throws an error is varHorizArray(1, intCol).Select . How can this code be changed to directly move the array to a new sheet? I would like to search for words in the new array.

```css
Sub SplitWithFormat()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim i As Long, V As Variant
    Dim varHorizArray As Variant
    Dim rge As Range
    Dim intCol As Integer
            
    
Set R = Range("d1", Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp))
For Each C In R
    With C
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        consecutivedelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=True, comma:=False, _
        Space:=True, other:=True, Otherchar:=vbLf

        Set rge = Selection
        varHorizArray = rge
        .Copy
        Range(.Offset(0, 1), Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
Next C

Application.CutCopyMode = False


For intCol = LBound(varHorizArray, 2) To UBound(varHorizArray, 2)
        Debug.Print varHorizArray(1, intCol)
    Next intCol
    
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
varHorizArray(1, intCol).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
​
```

Comment: You can't `select` an array...

Comment: Ah, as @jeeped likes to say, [turn key solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972255/arrays-in-excel-change-format-of-string) only leads to questions like these.

Comment: I just need this last part. How can the .TextToColumns function be changed from offset to a new sheet?

Comment: Your comment further confirms that you have very little understanding of the code you have XD _Please_ try to study it before asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly dump an array to a worksheet, just set a range with a similar dimension to your array and assign the array to that range.

```
Sheet1.Activate
Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, LBound(varHorizArray, 2)), Cells(UBound(varHorizArray), UBound(varHorizArray, 2))) = varHorizArray
```

Comment: when I placed that line I got a run time error 1004. Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: could be any thing, did you change the sheet name to actual sheet name from Sheet1. Is you array multi dimensional?

Comment: I left it as referencing sheet1 because my data is on sheet2 and the array is a few strings long and it is 1 dimensional

Comment: then please update your code accordingly. I gave you an example. Can't write tailor made code for every question. :) Hope you understand.